# Pythonic way to check if integer fits in 64 bits

Tags: python, integer, 64-bit

What is the Pythonic way (without using any external libraries) to check if an integer is small enough to fit in a 64 bit signed quantity?

Sorry if this question has been asked before!

Comment: @Mitch thanks for that!

Comment: No problem. I actually think Martijn's got you covered with a better answer than any on the more-or-less duplicate, in any case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just check the size with the [`int.bit_length()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

```
if integer_value.bit_length() <= 63:
```

The method takes the absolute value, so you want to leave a bit for the sign:

```
>>> (-2 ** 63).bit_length()
64
>>> (2 ** 63).bit_length()
64
```

Comment: And what is the recommended syntax for constructing the largest 64 bit integer?